# Django/Nginx: statics files are not served

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles, static-files

I try to deploy my Django project in a remote server using Nginx but my files are not served.

I guess my path is incorrect but don't really know why...

python3 manage.py collectstatic get all my files in intensecov_static folder.

/home/zebra/

```
- intensecov_app
    - intensecov
        - coverage (project)
        - manage.py
        - static
        - ...
- intensecov_static
    - css
       - style.css
    - images
    - ...
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_management/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization_settings/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/zebra/intensecov_static'
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/intensecov

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.80.9;
        root /home/zebra/intensecov_app;

        location /static {
                alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect off;
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wishing your nginx.conf you declared:

```
    location /static {
            alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static;
    }
```

Try this:

```
    location /static {
            alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static/;
    }
```

It seems nginx needs the trailing `/` to make the folder work.
Or at least that the serving of static-files broke when removing the trailing `/`.

Comment: Found another file with the destination path 'randomization/js/script.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.

Comment: To check whether or not the static-files are actually available, just surf to your app-admin.  If the static-files are served correctly you will get the correct look.  If not, you'll see a page without markup.

Comment: I got a page without markup static-files are not available... I try many change in settings but nothing works and I am a bit lost

Comment: Did you add the '/' at the end of the path in nginx?  This cause problems on my setup - so looks like a first problem to be solved.

Comment: yes I try location /static {alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static/; } AND location /static/ {alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static/; } and neither works !!!

Comment: I have deployed another project a month ago with EXACTLY the sames settings (I have checked lines by lines) and this previous project static-files are served ; I will become CRAZY !

Comment: I am SO SO SO STUPID !!! I had an error on the css files style.css instead of styles.css

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT is where all the static files are collected when you run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`
and STATIC_URL is what points to the STATIC_ROOT.

Check here for reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT

Changing the location in nginx file should solve the porblem.

Comment: i follow this OC tutorial (https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4425101-deployez-une-application-django/) and nginx file configuration... I do not understand how you suggest I should change nginx files?

Comment: when I run collectstatic, files have been collected in /home/zebra/intensecov_static (STATIC_ROOT defined in settings.py) and it contains css, images, etc... folders so I guess it is OK ; the path in nginx files is /home/zebra/intensecov_static so I should be OK?

Comment: Yes.. like S.D. has answered below... Did you try the trailing '/'. As in 
location /static/ {
                alias /home/zebra/intensecov_static;
 }
Notice the '/' after '/static'